# Play framework and WCF

Tags: .net, wcf, playframework, matlab-compiler

I have 2 applications: a play application and a WCF .net application. The play application needs the robust calculation capability of the WCF application(it has a matlab compiler).

I would like to know what's the best way to implement the communication between these 2 applications. Ideally I would want to have the play application sends a JSON object to WCF, WCF does the calculations and sends the result back to Play application.

Any ideas on how this would be implemented?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest that you go for ASP.NET Web API instead of WCF application. REST has wider compatibility then SOAP and the best way to implement RESTful service in .NET is ASP.NET Web API.

You can write code in server like this:

```
public class MathLabController : ApiController
{
    public MathResult Post(InputParam data)
    {
        // Do Calculation
        return new MathResult { Value = 3.14 };
    }
}
```

and then call that from browser (in your Play Framework app) using jQuery like this:

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'http://localhost:8080/api/MathLab',
    type: 'POST',
    data:JSON.stringify(inputParam),            
    contentType: 'application/json;charset=utf-8',
    success: function (mathResult) {
        alert(mathResult.Value);
    }
});
```

You don't need to do any JSON serialization/de-serialization in Web API. It is done automatically.